# JAVA Lucene not giving search results on Field?

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am creating a Lucene Document like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.add(new Field(FIELD_FOLDER_PATH,mSearchInput, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED ));
Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
document.add(new Field(FIELD_CONTENTS, reader));
indexWriter.addDocument(document);
```

When executing Query on CONTENTS and also using wild character * I am able to fetch results:

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser (Version.LUCENE_36,FIELD_CONTENTS, analyzer);
Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString+"*");
```

But when I am using the same Query for FIELD_FOLDER_PATH , I am getting no results:

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser (Version.LUCENE_36,FIELD_FOLDER_PATH, analyzer);
Query query = queryParser.parse(FolderPath+"*");
```

However only when I am providing the exact string , I am able to fetch the results.

My Question is : Why I am not able to use (*)  to fetch results in FIELD_FOLDER_PATH? Is it because of the way I am creating the field?

Comment: Which Analyzer are you using, when indexing and searching the FIELD_FOLDER_PATH field?

Answer (score 0):

You should use wildcard query to support this kind of feature.
This link would help :

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html

So what you should do exactly is create two queries one using queryparser and other using wildcard query , then use both the queries in a BooleanQuery with "SHOULD" clause for both the queries.

for details on boolean Query visit this link :

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html